# Display rich formatted text using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, database, richtextbox

I'm new to WPF so please bear with me if you find my question too primary. I want to get text from database and display this rich formatted document on my WPF app  So far as I know I should use RICHTEXTBOX. 
So, my question is should I store rich formatted text to database and just display it to window(which ideally the displaying will keep its format) or should I just store lines of words without formatting and format it when I display it on the window. Which way should I do and HOW I do that. Specific answer with codes how to store or how to display would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the text (rtf format) in the database and load it in a RichTextBox with something like this:

```
    TextRange documentTextRange = new TextRange(RICHTEXTBOXNAME.Document.ContentStart, RICHTEXTBOXNAME.Document.ContentEnd);
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FILENAME, FileMode.Open))
    {
      documentTextRange.Load(fs, DataFormats.Rtf);
    }
```

In this example the content is stored in a file, but there is no big difference.

RichTextBox cannot be completely compatible with all rtf stuff, so if you create an rtf from another source you can encounter some graphic glitch.